# Passing a value to a class keeps returning 0

Tags: c#

this might be a simple/dumb question but I'm trying to figure out why my code keeps returning 0. I don't think my syntax for passing the value is correct but I cant figure out the proper way of doing it.

```
    class ICESMARK
{
    static int ICECount = 0;
    public double average = 0;

    public double[] ICES = new double[8];
    public ICESMARK(double Mark)
    {
        Mark = ICES[ICECount];
        if (ICECount == (ICES.Length - 1))
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < ICES.Length; x++)
            {
               average += ICES[x];
            }

            average /= ICES.Length;
        }

        ICECount++;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ICESMARK[] ICE = new ICESMARK[8];
        //LABSMARK[] LAB = new LABSMARK[6];
        double userInput;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < ICE.Length ; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your mark for ICE{0}: ", counter + 1 );
            bool ifInt = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
            ICE[counter] = new ICESMARK(userInput);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ICE[1].average);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`ICE[1].average -` **Displays 0**

Also if anyone has a more efficient way of doing this, feel free to let me know. Except for the average, is gotta be a calculation, cant use the built in method.

Comment: where are you using marks parameter which you passing to the constructor? Did not get your code sorry.. What you want to achieve?

Comment: There are a lot of problems here.  You should be defining a function that takes values, has a return type, and returns a value.  Instead you're directly modifying members of the class you've defined as public.  The point of a class is to encapsulate data, and only expose what is needed.

Comment: like you get the list of ints from the user, then pass them into a getAvg function.  I'm not sure why your constructor calculates an average.  Just change that to a function, and pass in List<int> or int[]

Comment: Okay sorry if is messy, I'm very new, specially to classes/methods. ICE = quiz, I want the user to input the mark he got on each quiz, and calculate his average.

Comment: yea a function will be better, I'm using classes just for the sake of learning how to use a class.

Comment: `ICE[1] Displays the class namespace for some reason lol` What else do you expect it to return? You might wanted to use `ICE[1].SomeProperty`

Comment: yea I just edited that mistake sorry, I meant to use ICE[1].average, which returns 0.

Comment: well, your `ICECount` never fulfills the condition to calculate the average, so it always stays 0. You only add one Mark.. Use Methods for that. It's much more readable

Comment: also `Mark = ICES[ICECount];` Is this some kind of 2020 technology or why are setting Mark to 0 even before the ICES are set... your Mark parameter becomes useless. Your code is waay to messy, sorry. That's hard to help

Comment: yea it was supposed to be the other way around, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to clarify that yes there are easier ways to solve this, but the entire point of the project was to use a class and it specifically says I cant use built in methods such as "array.average".

Sorry that my code was super messy, I was honestly all over the place and very confused. Having that said I finally arrived to this solution. Thanks to everyone who tried to help! really appreciate it, some tips here were very helpful in solving and cleaning up my code.

```
    class ICESMARK
{
    public static int ICECount = 0;
    public static double average = 0;

    public ICESMARK(double Mark)
    {

        average += Mark;
        if (ICECount < 8) { ICECount++; }
        if (ICECount == 8) { average /= ICECount;}            
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ICESMARK[] ICE = new ICESMARK[8];

        double userInput;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < ICE.Length ; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your mark for ICE{0}: ", counter + 1 );
            bool ifInt = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
            ICE[counter] = new ICESMARK(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine(ICESMARK.ICECount);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ICESMARK.average);
        Console.WriteLine(ICESMARK.ICECount);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest code to get your work done:

```
void Main()
{
    double[] ICE = new double[8];

    double userInput = 0.0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < ICE.Length; counter++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter your mark for ICE {counter}: ");

        bool isNumerical = false;

        while(!isNumerical)
            isNumerical = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);

        ICE[counter] = userInput;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Average : " + ICE.Average());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

### How it works:

1. Removed all the frills, you don't need an extra class just for this purpose
2. Made it mandatory for code to enter valid double value to fill all the slots
3. Finally used `Linq Average` to calculate `Average` value